# How can I use wsimport to generate a webservice client which wsdl requires authentication?

Tags: web-services, authentication, wsimport

I'm trying to generate a webservice client using wsimport, but the wsdl requires authentication.

I'm using a command like this:
wsimport https://username:password@url?wsdl

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 13):

After running your command you should get a message complaining about a missing web authorization file.

What you need to do is create an authorization file (usually the default name/location for it is $HOME_DIRECTORY/.metro/auth, but check the previous error message, you'll get the hint from there).
Inside this file you just write the line: "https://username:password@url?wsdl"

Once the file is created, run the wsimport command again omitting the username/password info, like this:

> wsimport https://url?wsdl

Hope it helps.

Comment: It Works !! I however face problem because my Username had an @ so I escaped that by replacing my username asdas@xx.com with asdas%40xx.com

Answer (score 4):

```
wsimport -Xauthfile C:\resources\META-INF\auth.conf https://url?wsdl
```

---

auth.conf

```
https://USERNAME:PASWORD@url?wsdl
```

Comment: how to escape special characters in the password/username?