# Java WS - Creating client stub using wsimport

Tags: java, wsdl, wsimport

I am trying to generate a sample stub by using a open WS URL http://www.webservicex.net/geoipservice.asmx?WSDL

When I try to run the wsimport I get below error

```
[DEBUG] Authorization file "C:\Users\User Name\\.metro\auth" not
found.
```

I tried the suggestion from following link 
[How can I use wsimport to generate a webservice client which wsdl requires authentication?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6293722/how-can-i-use-wsimport-to-generate-a-webservice-client-which-wsdl-requires-authe)

but could not create the folder `.metro` as it is not a valid name.

How do I generate the stub or create this folder ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should download the wsdl and run wsimport on it.

If the wsdl has a WS policy that requires authentication, comment these ws policy elements out to simply generate the wsdl.

You can also test with tools e.g. soapUI.

BTW what web service framework are you using?

Comment: Thanks David. I am doing my first tutorial on WS and trying to use the client using the SOAP. How do I specify the local path ? It will not take path like "C:\...". Also what is the format in which i should save it .XML or .WSDL ?

Comment: David. I got it working. I saved it as .wsdl in my local folder C:\geowsdl.wsdl and ran the command on that. It generated the class files. Why will it not work with direct URL ? It does not have any authentication stuff in the wsdl so something might be wrong in the way i was trying to use it.

Comment: There are lots of reasons why a direct URL could possibly not work. For once, the server might apply things like HTTP BASIC authentication. Secondly your cmd prompt may not have any proxy defined but you are in a network that requires one... It's always easier to download the wsdl.

Answer (score 0):

For creating folder with name starting with "." like ".metro" actually name it as ".metro." ( one "." extra in the end), then it will be created. Works for windows 7