# Generating stubs using remote WSDL which requires username and password using SSL certificates?

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, wsdl, openssl

Could you please help me about the steps to be followed for generating stubs using wsimport.
In my case my WSDL requires username and password if it has to be downloaded using certificate via SSL.
I used the command `wsimport -keep -s` path url.

But it is not working. how to provide username and password to get the WSDL?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I use wsimport to generate a webservice client which wsdl requires authentication?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6293722/how-can-i-use-wsimport-to-generate-a-webservice-client-which-wsdl-requires-authe)

Answer (score 1):

In case the WSDL Expects user credentials use the below

> C:>wsimport -keep -d D:/XXX -Xauthfile WS_Auth.txt
>   {http}://CustomURL.com/Metrics/Services/MetricDrop.asmx?WSDL

Where WS_Auth.txt contains:

> {http}://domainName\username:password@WSDL_URL//Metrics/Services/MetricDrop.asmx?WSDL

Comment: Thank you for the help. But still i'm getting the error. [ERROR] java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative names present. in my authentication file i kept as ' http://16.175.217.24:8443\admin\username:password@https://16.175.217.24:8443/cfcc/control?view=services/AdministratorService?WSDL' Is there any prob with my file?

Comment: @Sushma : What is the error? And can you open the WSDL file in browser using the credentials?

Comment: Your auth file should contain "{https}://username:password@url?wsdl"

Comment: Ok. I tried like that also, i'm able to access the WSDL via URL, but when i use wsimport i'm repeatedly getting the same cetification error. What might be the issue. Actually the certificate in the URL having the same host name as i specified in the wsimport but still i'm getting the erro?

Comment: See if this link helps for cert error : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8443081/how-are-ssl-certificate-server-names-resolved-can-i-add-alternative-names-using/8444863#8444863

Comment: *"But still I'm getting the error... java.security.cert.CertificateException"* - this looks like a different problem (none of this was mentioned in your post). You should open a new question and thank Maas by accepting his answer. When you accept his answer, future visitors will be able to locate the correct answer quickly.